# TypeScript type that copies another object type, but changes type of properties based on their original type condition

Tags: typescript

I need a TypeScript type that copies another object type, but changes type of properties based on their original type condition. And also do so to all nested and deep nested properties.

For example a type `DateToStrings<T>` that would turn all type `Date` properties into type `string` properties. It would look like this:

If I have a class:

```ts
class Milk {
  brandName: string,
  prince: number,
  dealExpiredAt: Date,
  properties: {
    expirationDetails: {
      expiredAt: Date
    }
  }
}
```

The type `DateToStrings<Milk>` would be:

```ts
{
  brandName: string,
  price: number,
  dealExpiredAt: string,
  properties: {
    expirationDetails: {
      expiredAt: string
    }
  }
}
```

Would really appreciate some help as I don't really have a direction to approach it, any tips or known types / type packages that do something similar?

Comment: `class Milk: {` is not valid syntax. Do you have a `class` or `type`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use recursive conditional type. Not all edge cases covered, but for above example something like this should work:

```
type DateToStrings<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Date
    ? string
    : T[K] extends Array<infer I>
    ? Array<DateToStrings<I>>
    : T[K] extends object
    ? DateToStrings<T[K]>
    : T[K]
}

type MilkTransformed = DateToStrings<Milk>

const foo: MilkTransformed = {
    brandName: 'string',
    prince: 123,
    dealExpiredAt: 'Date',
    properties: {
        expirationDetails: {
            // Expected error: Type 'Date' is not assignable to type 'string'
            expiredAt: new Date
        }
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsglgGwNZQLxQN4Cgq6gIwCcBDAOwBMA5YgWwgC4oBnYQuUgcwBoc8w3SAYwZRSAVxr4IhHnijkIxBAFEAHmDiEI5AILBGAEWLAIsvoQD2kQsDgQmjbHLkR1m43AukDEYMUQOmLzOzq4aWrr6UEYmwc4AvnGJiVigkNHGEAAqFgDKrOwcTAA8WQB8aEFyANoA0lDsUEgQIBYAZlBZALqMWXVdUK4mFEwZsXIA-MwFnHG9-YOqw%20SjOoQkIMXsbdJQAJJlcVNrG8Ux2XkzRcUHh3LztQNDECNQFvgAVhCCwEdjF-kBNc%20o87ngHl0sCk0tB4MgsiRSEw2hZCHRyJVzjlAYUSnCkIcsIIvCwoCiLIx8QiyMjUejKk48EQyFRaCIAOQsIHssy4fjsYSMACMACYAMy8%20SKFRuCJ6Rjs848uL8KzSWz2RxxFyyjxeHx%20AJakIhAD0pqgakgP20g3WqN64Ggisy7Iao1IFmAUGITCYcA4pGI%20AQ0GAFigMKgnKu7O1JrCmm08tEEAA7v947hEnJkkA)

Comment: Here you have one edge case, when property is a tuple `foo: [Date, Date]` :) Please don't treat this comment as a criticism of an answer. You have my upvote

Comment: Yeah, also functions taking dates as parameters or returning date/object or array with date